# Debian packaging: Version-dependent `Provides` relationship

Tags: dpkg

Suppose I have a .deb package `alpha`, which currently depends on `beta 1.0.1` and `gamma 1.0.1`. My newer version, `beta 2.0.1` now includes all of `gamma`. Is it possible to have a version-dependent `Provides` keyword in `debian/control`? e.g. in `beta`'s control file

```
Package: beta
Architecture: any
Depends: python3, foo, bar
Provides: gamma (but only in version >=2.0.1)
...
```

or should I update the `Depends` field accordingly in the reverse dependency's control file, in this case `alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

`Provides` only applies to the package which contains it. Your old `beta` packages presumably don’t have the field, so they don’t provide `gamma` and won’t satisfy `alpha`’s dependency. If you add `Provides: gamma` to version 2.0.1 of the `beta` package, that package will provide `gamma` and thus satisfy the dependency (with some restrictions), but it won’t suddenly cause earlier versions of `beta` to satisfy it.

In more detail, your existing `beta` 1.0.1 package presumably says

```
Package: beta
Version: 1.0.1
Priority: …
Section: …
…
```

and your new 2.0.1 package would say

```
Package: beta
Version: 2.0.1
Priority: …
Section: …
…
Provides: gamma
…
```

This new entry only applies to the 2.0.1 package, the 1.0.1 package doesn’t change.

Note that unversioned `Provides` only satisfy unversioned dependencies. If `alpha` depends on `gamma` with a version restriction (*e.g.* `>= 2.0`), you’ll need a versioned `Provides` in `beta` — but that doesn’t say anything about *`beta`*’s versions, only the version of `gamma` which it is equivalent to.

See [the Debian Policy section on `Provides`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides) for details.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought - I got tripped up at:
"The debian/control file contains the most vital (and version-independent) information about the source package and about the binary packages it creates."

My over-thinking somehow led me to believe 'version independent' implied 'all of the older versions in the repo will also take this as the universal truth'.